# SQL query to display result

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is the table in database:

```
Product     Type1       Type2       Type3       Manufacturer
Notebook    50 Pages    100 Pages   150 Pages   KP Mills
Pen         Blue        Black       Red         Parker
```

What should be the SQL Query to display the result in following format:

```
Product     Type        Manufacturer
Notebook    50 Pages    KP Mills
Notebook    100 Pages   KP Mills
Notebook    150 Pages   KP Mills
Pen         Blue        Parker
Pen         Black       Parker
Pen         Red         Parker
```

Comment: You need to select each of the type columns separately.  Read up on the `UNION [ALL]` operator to combine these.

Comment: Hi John, Can we do this with the help of case statement

Comment: do you have to use a case statement?

Comment: No, I don't see how a `CASE` statement could help you here.

Comment: Okay.. Thanks John for quick and correct response :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select product, 
       type1 as type,
       manufacturer
from the_table
union all
select product, 
       type2,
       manufacturer
from the_table
union all
select product, 
       type3,
       manufacturer
from the_table
order by product, type;
```